# Which class levels are an Oracle mysteries and curses based on?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-levels, oracle

I'm not very familiar with the [Oracle](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/) class.

If I understand it correctly, the abilities and spells for the [Mysteries](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Oracle/#Mystery) are based on Oracle level, whereas the [curse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/oracle-curses/) abilities are based on Oracle level + half other class levels.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Are you just confirming whether your understanding is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Yes, an Oracle's mystery only uses Oracle levels, whereas curses also scale with other hit dice.

By default, when a Pathfinder class ability refers to a character's "level", it is referring to their levels in that specific class. From the *Core Rulebook*, the multiclassing section on page 31:

> Note that there are a number of effects and prerequisites that rely on the character's level or Hit Dice. Such effects are always based on the total number of levels or Hit Dice a character possesses, not just those from one class. The exception to this is class abilities, most of which are based on the total number of class levels that a character possesses of that particular class.

The Oracle's [Mystery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Oracle/#Mystery) is one of those class abilities. Since the feature only mentions level, we can conclude it uses the general rule (above) and refers to levels in the Oracle class.

> the mystery manifests in a number of ways as the oracle gains levels.

In contrast, the [Curse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/oracle-curses/) feature explicitly says that it also scales with non-Oracle hit dice (i.e., other class levels and racial hit dice), divided by 2 and rounded down.

> An oracle’s curse is based on her oracle level plus one for every two levels or Hit Dice other than oracle.

Example: Suppose a [mimic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/mimic/), which has 7 racial hit dice, somehow had 5 Oracle levels and 1 Fighter level. For their Mysteries, their effective level only counts Oracle levels (5). But for their Curses, their effective level equals 5 + ((7+1)/2), for a total of 9.